# Which 3rd party Analytics SDK support tvOS?

Tags: tvos

I found out that none of those are supporting tvOS : Google Analytics, Fabric, Flurry. So I wonder is there any Analytics SDK that I could use?

Comment: We have the same issue. There even seems to be no Apple analytics right now. I've posted to support forums for the main analytics providers but no word yet. Considering just building our own basic system.

Comment: There is a blog post from someone that mentioned they were able to put Google Analytics in their project.

I have not tried it myself yet but I thought I'd let you know about it just in case: https://medium.com/@dhashvir/google-analytics-for-apple-tvos-5074add68f3f

Comment: Just an update about the post claiming to use Google Analytics I mentioned above. I had some time to test it out and it does NOT work right now, at least not for me. It works fine on simulator but then gives a compile error when building for device.

Comment: I know. Someone just copy paste google's instructions to his blog. It still doesn't work.

Answer (score 7):

We just added support for tvOS for Google Analytics: https://github.com/analytics-pros/GA-Tracker-for-Apple-tvOS. Let me know if you have any questions

Comment: Just a few lines of code, awesome job! The standard Google implementations are super heavy.

Answer (score 1):

For Google Analytics, if you're using the [TVML](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/index.html) and [TVJS](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSFrameworkReference/index.html) to build your app, you can use [tvjs_google_analytics](https://github.com/drichardson/tvjs_google_analytics).

If you are not using TVML+TVJS, it looks like the Google Analytics SDK for iOS now [supports bitcode](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671), though they apparently do not have a tvOS target yet so you'll probably have to wait until Google gets around to adding that.

Answer (score 0):

Adobe Heartbeat has been available for TvOS for a month now. I have tested it out and it seems to work. You can find it at their github page:
https://github.com/Adobe-Marketing-Cloud/video-heartbeat/tree/master/sdks/ios/libs

Answer (score 0):

Try Facebook Analytics for both iOS & tvOS apps,

https://github.com/facebook/facebook-ios-sdk