# Analytics SDK for tvOS

Tags: google-analytics, flurry, tvos, apple-tv, twitter-fabric

I'm about to ship an app for tvOS and I would like to include some basic analytics in it, but I couldn't find any SDK available for this platform.

I already integrated the beta version of Fabric but only the Crashlytics SDK is working on tvOS. Answers is not available.

I've been looking at Google Analytics, Flury, Mixpanel but so far, it doesn't seem like anyone has a working SDK. Does anybody have some suggestions?

Thanks!

**UPDATE:**
Fabric started a beta for Answers on tvOS. http://answers.io/blog/introducing-answers-for-os-x-and-tvos-beta

Comment: Please search for questions first before posting them. This question is a duplicate of http://stackoverflow.com/questions/33455437/which-3rd-party-analytics-sdk-support-tvos

Answer (score 0):

For Google Analytics, if you're using the [TVML](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/LanguagesUtilities/Conceptual/ATV_Template_Guide/index.html) and [TVJS](https://developer.apple.com/library/tvos/documentation/TVMLJS/Reference/TVJSFrameworkReference/index.html) to build your app, you can use [tvjs_google_analytics](https://github.com/drichardson/tvjs_google_analytics).

If you are not using TVML+TVJS, it looks like the Google Analytics SDK for iOS now [supports bitcode](https://code.google.com/p/analytics-issues/issues/detail?id=671), though they apparently do not have a tvOS target yet so you'll probably have to wait until Google gets around to adding that.

Answer (score 0):

We could use 'Flurry-iOS-SDK/FlurryTVOS', '8.3.0' for tvOS Analytics.